# How to make template and label selection mandatory before merge request in Gitlab?

Tags: gitlab

I am using [gitlab templates](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/description_templates.html#overview) (and labels also), but want to make them mandatory to submit a request. Not able to find needed reference to so.

Edit:
what I am looking for is some mandatory check i.e like without selecting any of template (and label) you can't post request.

Comment: But it's right on that page? "Setting a default template for issues and merge requests"?

Comment: @seth I think that means you can give some default templates to user ( developer) but what I am looking for is some mandatory check i.e without selecting any of them you can't post request.
Thanks

Comment: If it's the default, it's a mandatory layout? What's actually missing? What more do you need?

Comment: Is it possible to disable the `create request` button If the description box is empty?
@Seth

Comment: No idea. [This](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/push_rules/push_rules.html) might be relevant.

Comment: Although it's definitely a valid technical question, I think it's controversial conceptually.  
With Pipeline as Code you do want to define your pipeline as you like in your sources.
Hence anyone can raise MR with just dummy job in `.gitlab-ci.yml`, overcoming all the rules.  
If you have sane PR review process, that should flag it.  
And you can configure project settings to require certain number of approvers or even specify who should do that.
You can of course write something custom, e.g. external job that does the validation of the pipeline script, but it would be some work.

Comment: I am sorry @Ivan , can you please explain your comment.
Thanks

Comment: Which part? 1) conceptual 2) PR review 3) external validation job?